# Columns to Rows --Netezza

Tags: netezza

In netezza need to convert columns to rows please help for example

```
emp id dept
abc 10  CS
xyz 20  Maths
```

need output as

```
abc
10
CS
xyz
20
Maths
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL to accomplish this, but you need to decide what data type the target column should be.

You don't specify the types for your sample data, but it might be something like this:

```
create table row_split (emp varchar(40), id integer, dept varchar(15));
```

In this case you would need to cast the columns to something that would accommodate the data types of each source column.  In this case, varchar(40) is the obvious choice.

```
select emp::varchar(40) result_column from row_split
union all
select id::varchar(40) result_column from row_split
union all
select dept::varchar(40) result_column from row_split;


 RESULT_COLUMN
---------------
 Maths
 xyz
 20
 CS
 abc
 10
(6 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is much easier way to do this using `nzsql` netezza querying tool (if you are using on linux / unix to access netezza database)

`nzsql` offers output `Field` delimiter option.

Let's assume data is stored in employee table and all the environment variables are set and exported for host, username, password and database.

`export NZ_USER=<username>`
`export NZ_PASSWORD=<password>`
`export NZ_DATABASE=<database>`
`export NZ_HOST=<hostname>`

```
nzsql -F $'\n' -Atc 'select * from employee;'

abc
10
CS
xyz
20
Maths
```

Only downside to this solution is, it only works on Linux / Unix where you can use `nzsql` utility.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convert columns to rows,
then shouldn't you be expecting:

```
emp  abc xyz
id   10  20
dept CS  Maths
```

If you you are trying to transpose a matrix, you may use `TRANSPOSE` procedure.